Does "member" mean "child" in the ECMA-262 spec?
I'm reading the ECMA-262 spec. The spec starts by giving definitions, but they keep using the word "member" in a context that is odd to me:

4.4.5 primitive value - member of one of the types Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, BigInt, Symbol, or String as defined in clause

Another example:

4.4.6 object - member of the type Object

I've always understood these words to be defined as:

Member: a reference within a type or class - such as a method or property.
Child: a type or class that inherits from the current type or class.

So do I have the correct understanding of the ECMA spec, that when they say member they mean child? It doesn't make sense that an object derived from Object, connected by type chain would be a "member" of the "Object" type.

I am a member of the Human Race. My cat is a member of the Very Bad Orange Cat Association.

Take note of the capitalization: object != Object.

@Pointy - that must be what they were thinking.  I hadn't even considered it that way.  It's still really using poor language choices in my opinion.  I can't think of any other spec I've read that words it that way.

@JamieMarshall being member of a type is very spec-oriented language. It's mostly maths language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics) "member" is something that belongs in some set. And the spec talks about the types like Null and Undefined. Which are also sets with one element (a.k.a. "member") each. The type Boolean has two elements. Then there are the types for String and Number which have infinite elements but are still sets that you can reason about. The language is entirely appropriate when talking about maths-y terms.
